# When did the Hand realize that Daredevil was blind?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil, daredevil-2015

### Caution, *Daredevil* Season 2 spoilers below.

In "The Dark at the End of the Tunnel," the Hand clearly know that Daredevil is blind. They explicitly hold their breath and don't use weapons so that he can't track them. Previously, they had simply been stopping/masking their heartbeats.

> STICK: Listen very carefully. You've been tracking their weapons. So they dropped 'em. Tracking heartbeats is kids' stuff. Time to go deeper. Track their breath. Sooner or later, they gotta... (exhales deeply) exhale.

In the earlier episode "Guilty as Sin," we see a ninja watching Murdock's apartment as Daredevil, Stick and Electra enter it, so they could deduce his identity by this point, at least.

Were they masking their heartbeats before they knew he was blind? If so, when did they figure it out?

Comment: i cant remember but did they see him with stick earlier? cause i believe they were trained to stop their heartbeats to fight stick specificly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From S01E09, "[Speak of the Devil](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Speak_of_the_Devil)"

> *Daredevil:* I knew no one was in the building. I made that mistake with the Russians once, learned from it.
>
> *Nobu:* But you did not know I was here.
>
> *Daredevil:* No. You slowed your heart... lowered your body temperature.
>
> *Nobu:* The old fool has taught you in our ways.

Nobu, the NYC head of the Hand, both saw him with Stick and saw Daredevil's lack of ability to counter the Hand's slowed heartbeat.